# Is there any way to implement download attribute in Safari

Tags: javascript, safari

I am developing an Calendar App. Back-end will return the file name and ics format string to front-end in JSON. Then I wanna use JavaScript to force download the ics file. This is my code:

```
function downloadFile(fileName, content) {
    var aLink = document.createElement('a');
    var blob = new Blob([content]);
    var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
    evt.initEvent("click");
    aLink.download = fileName;
    aLink.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    aLink.dispatchEvent(evt);
}
```

I pass the fileName and content to this function, and it will generate a link to download this file. This works good in Chrome, but it cannot work in Safari 7. Is it because that safari does not support `download` attribute? Is there any way to implement this?

Comment: You could have a server side script return the ics with appropriate mime/content disposition headers and direct a hidden iframe to it

Comment: Should work in Safari 6 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL.createObjectURL

Comment: Thanks! Actually I tried iframe and it works. I want to know is there any way to implement `saveAs` in Safari?

Comment: @Ciel Yes, it is called updating your browser.